Is it possible to "label" Segwit spendable output ScriptPubKeys with arbitrary bytes?
If one created a Redeem Script for a transaction output following a P2SH-P2WPKH pattern but with bytes prepended, something like:
OP_PUSHBYTES_8 41206c6162656c2e OP_DROP OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <20 byte address>


Would it be valid; spendable by a Segwit transaction?

Can an arbitrary bytes "label" be put into a Segwit P2WPKH type output by some other means? One alternative approach would be to use a separate output OP_RETURN with a reference to the output number, but I'm wondering if the label bytes can be in the same output.






Would it be valid; spendable by a Segwit transaction?



It is valid to create such an output, but it would not be considered a segwit output (see BIP141), and thus not spendable using a segwit input.
Instead, the script would be interpreted according to bare script rules instead, which permit spending such an output with empty scriptSig (and empty scriptWitness).



Can an arbitrary bytes "label" be put into a Segwit P2WPKH type output by some other means?



No. A P2WPKH output contains script that is exactly OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <20 byte pubkey hash>.
If you absolutely want to put your labelling inside the output, your only option is to grind the public key until you hit one whose hash conveys your label (which costs 256N tries for an N-byte label), or to appropriate some of the low-order bits of the amount sent.
